# Javascript/jquery append a variable with a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched around and don't think I am asking a duplicated question, if I am, I'll delete immediately.

I have this:

```
$('#dti').text(result3.toFixed(2));
```

The question is how do I append this with '%'

I am hardcoding a % sign in now but it shows even if there is no value...

Comment: What do you mean by no value? Is it `0` or `null` or an empty string?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - A TypeError would be thrown if `result3` was anything other than a number, and if it was `0` it would return `0.00`, so I don't think it could ever be "empty" really.

Comment: TJ might not have looked at the error console before posting, there might still be an error there.

Comment: @JamesAllardice - That is correct. We don't know the possible values of `result3` that is why I have asked a question to OP. You can see it up there.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - Yeah, I know, my comment was meant more as a complement to yours than an argument against it. The question can't really be answered effectively until the question is cleared up.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#dti').text(result3.toFixed(2) + (result3?"%":""));
```

If `result3` can never be emtpy or null but a `value >= 0` and you don't want to show `0%` then you can try this

```
$('#dti').text(result3 ? (result3.toFixed(2) + "%") : "");
```

Comment: `(false).toFixed(2)` would throw an error, so the check in the second half of the snippet won't work.

Comment: @Douglas - That is why I have asked question to OP in the questions comment section. Based on that we can check the null or other condition

Comment: Now we don't know if `restult3` is `0` whether OP wants to show `%` or not.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`$('#dti').text(num = result3.toFixed(2) ? num + '%' : '');`